# Wireless power through air

Tags: wireless, wireless-charging

I know this might be far fetched. In normal everyday life, we have huge amounts of data traveling through the air in the form of electromagnetic radiation. But what if instead of transmitter data through this channel we instead transmit low energy power. Where by at the receiver side we use the antenna or a custom built transducer that will be able to convert this transmitted power into a clean 5V DC voltage. Is this even feasible?

Comment: This is rfid.  C

Comment: This is what Nikola Tesla was attempting (reportedly) to do when he "accidentally" discovered Radio Transmission (before Marconi). Bottom line, he failed only in that the amounts of power transferred are infinitesimally tiny.

Comment: @J.Raefield well I am really invested in finding new ways to power relatively small electronics with the resources we have unlimited acces to such as the electromagnetic spectrum that surrounds us 24/7. Would be great if this can be achieved!

Answer (score 2):

Propagation of electromagnetic waves through the air has relatively high loss and thus bad efficiency. E.g. at 2.4GHz and 1m distance, power loss is factor 1:10‘000 (isotropic antenna model).

That is not a big problem for signal transmission, but it is a huge problem for energy transmission.

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment because you haven't realistically addressed the OP's question. Consider highly directional antennas are good at transmitting and receiving power. All the op wants to know is if he can achieve 5 volts. Also the propagation loss through air that you talk about is nonesense.

Comment: Joey asked for feasability in general and I tried to give him some general insights. BTW, what exactly differentiates answer from comment?